# Kentico - Portal + ASPX

Tags: kentico

**Question**
I wonder if ASPX + Portal on the same website is **officialy** supported, using *Kentico 11 CMS*.

**Research**
Documentation states, that:

> If required, the Portal Engine and ASPX Templates models can be
>   combined on a single website. For example, you can place pages using
>   ASPX templates onto a portal engine website, and even insert custom
>   ASPX pages implementing your own applications. On the other hand, you
>   can create ASPX page templates with areas that can be edited through
>   the portal engine.

On the other hand, only these modes are listed in the *officially supported* section:

- Portal Engine
- ASPX Templates
- MVC

Due to this I'm not really sure how the thing is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this post date, Portal + ASPX is still supported in v11.

BUT if you want to keep up with Kentico and where the market seems to be trending, you will move towards MVC.  Take a [look at Kentico's Roadmap](https://www.kentico.com/product/roadmap), it's clear they are taking an MVC first approach.

If you're not sold on MVC yet and considering ASPX, I challenge you to take a hard look at that and ask yourself why.  Anything you can do in ASPX can be done just as easy in Portal with webparts and/or global handlers/events.